How to train the simplest GAN? Uniform 1D noise to learn a Gaussian
I am starting a PhD, and we are trying to understand the simplest GAN so we can later use it for more complex goals. We want a GAN to learn to approximate a gaussian distribution from a 1D uniform noise input. This is what we are getting.

This is the architecture we are using

Input: 1D uniform distribution

Optimizer SGD

Loss function BCE

Generator: 1 layer of 3 neurons, with sigmoid activation function and the output layer

Discriminator: 1 layer of 4 neurons, with sigmoid activation function and sigmoid output

Generator and discriminator initialized with Xavier normal

Learning rate 0.01


I am pretty new to this topic, so any comment will be welcome. Thank you!
PS in this address you can see the full gif https://www.reddit.com/r/Gans/comments/1gph2w6/understanding_the_simplest_gan/
